# Class with custom allocator

Tags: c++, linux, c++17

I don't know whether it is possible to achieve.

I'm planning to build a storage library. Internally I'm planning to use STL's.
Good thing about STL's is I can pass my own custom allocator. Suppose i have a following class

```
class mylibclass
{
private:
std::unordered_map<std::string,void *>__HashMap;
std::vector<someclass>__unusedsamplevector;

public:
mylibclass(){}
};
```

When the application writer wants to use this library, he/she should be able to pass his own custom allocator for `unordered_map` and even for the `vector`. No getting how to achieve it.

Note: This is just a sample code. Just for reference

Comment: An allocator is a template parameter of STL containers. You could make `mylibclass` a template that takes allocator class as a parameter; or, you can make use of [`polymorhoic_allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator) and have your users pass an implementation of [`memory_resource`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/memory_resource) to `mylibclass`'s constructor.

Comment: i can try taking template class as a parameter,but as in my example i have 2 stls with different data types.How i can achieve this if i take it as template parameter?

Comment: You could take two template parameters, one allocator for each class. Or, you can take one allocator, and use `std::allocator_traits::rebind_alloc` to manufacture allocators for the required types from that.

Comment: taking no of parameters is not feasible.Ideally they should pass one allocator class.that i need to use for different types

Comment: So, in what way does a solution involving `std::allocator_traits::rebind_alloc` fail to satisfy your requirements?

Comment: actually i dont know how to use it.any examples you can guide me?

Comment: `template <typename Alloc> class mylibclass { std::vector<someclass, typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<someclass>> myVector;};` Something along these lines.

Comment: Thank you.One more query.suppose if i have my own custom allocator and if the user doesn't pass any i can pass my own.Like template <typename Alloc=myalloc>.Since myalloc is a templated class i have to specify data type right

Comment: You can specify any data type, since it's going to be rebound anyway.

Comment: thanks a lot.i will rewrite the code and update.Thank you very much

Comment: if i want to seperate my definitions(.hpp) and implementation(.cpp) using template will create me issue during compilation

Comment: ["Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/495021) . If you don't want to use templates, then, as I mentioned in the first comment, you need to use polymorphic allocators (new in C++17). Those could be provided at run time, rather than compile time.